# Is the compareTo method (in the Comparable interface) recursive?

Tags: java, recursion

I am implementing the Comparable interface, and using it to compare the names of sports teams. I noticed that this was the simplest implementation of the compareTo method. I was wondering why the method compareTo refers to itself in the body of the method. Isn't that some sort of never-ending recursion? How can you implement a method by defining it as itself?

```
public int compareTo(Team x)
{
    return teamName.compareTo(x.teamName);
}
```

Comment: Is `teamName` the same as `this`?

Comment: Ah. Sorry if I caused you any confusion, because I gave you that code in the answer to your previous question, without fully explaining it. But the answers below are correct: `teamName` is a String. The compareTo method of Team is implemented by deferring to the compareTo method of its String field. But the recursion is not never-ending, because String.compareTo doesn't call any other compareTo methods; it's implemented in terms of operations on primitive elements. (Actually, you can implement a method in terms of itself; e.g., `int x() { return x(); }` but it will blow up if you call it!)

Answer (score 3):

You don't present the complete code that puzzles you, but presumably the method you do present belongs to a class `Team` of some package, and presumably that class's `teamName` field is of a type different from `Team` (I'll suppose it's `java.lang.String`).  In that case, the method you present is not recursive at all.  Method `some.package.Team.compareTo(some.package.Team)` invokes method `java.lang.String.compareTo(java.lang.String)`, which is a completely separate method.

Comment: The two methods are not even invoked on the same object, though that in itself is not a necessary condition for the call to be characterized as recursive.

Comment: For completeness' sake, I'll just add that both methods just happen to have the same name (because the `Comparable` interface requires so), even though they are completely distinct. By definition of recursion, for a method to be recursive it would have to call itself, which is not the case. Two individuals aren't the same, just because they both happen to be called Smith, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If `teamName` is of type `String` String's [compareTo(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

`teamName` is probably a `String`.
So it uses `String.compareTo()` method.